# In erlang, how do I interpret the `+` operator in `fun erlang:'+'/2`

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, elixir

I'm new to `Erlang` but have some experience with `Elixir`. As I've been trying to learn Erlang while experimenting with the RabbitMQ implementation of RAFT, [ra](https://github.com/rabbitmq/ra), I've come across a [line in erlang `Machine = {simple, fun erlang:'+'/2, 0},`](https://github.com/rabbitmq/ra/blob/a7d38142c4e74c8214636b4416e815c503ee0319/README.md?plain=1#L114)

```
Machine = {simple, fun erlang:'+'/2, 0},
```

So, in  `{simple, fun erlang:'+'/2, 0},`, this looks like it is creating a tuple. The first item in the tuple is an `atom` named `simple`, the next `function` and the last an `integer`:

```
{atom, function, integer}
```

I don't understand what the function `fun erlang:'+'/2` is doing in this context. The `/2` means it should take 2 params. Is the `'+'` just an addition operator? If so, is this a simple `sum` function and I am overthinking it? The erlang docs say ["An atom is to be enclosed in single quotes (') if it does not begin with a lower-case letter or if it contains other characters than alphanumeric characters, underscore (_), or @."](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#atom)

In the given [context](https://github.com/rabbitmq/ra/blob/a7d38142c4e74c8214636b4416e815c503ee0319/README.md?plain=1#L114) that I'm seeing this code, it states `State machine that implements the logic`, which is leading me to understand this state machine as being named with the atom `simple`, performs addition, and saves the result in the last item of the tuple.

Is it equivalent of doing `&:erlang.+/2` in elixir? [Doc Reference](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules-and-functions.html#function-capturing)

Any context would really help.

Comment: Yes, it's the addition operator.

Comment: Why is it in single quotes?

Comment: Because it doesn't begin with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got it exactly right - this function is just the addition operator, and it is enclosed in single quotes because it doesn't start with a lowercase letter. `fun erlang:'+'/2` is equivalent to Elixir's `&:erlang.+/2`.

You can call it using function syntax instead of operator syntax:

```
> erlang:'+'(1,2).
3
```

And you can use it as a higher-order function:

```
> lists:foldl(fun erlang:'+'/2, 0, [1, 2, 3]).
6
```

(Of course, you'd usually use `lists:sum/1` instead of the latter example.)

Comment: Thanks! I was really overthinking this. Between the elixir -> erlang difference with Atoms and Single Quotes, it seemed obvious, but also not too obvious.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Erlang documentation(s), this particular usage is one of the forms for specifying [Fun expression](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#fun-expressions), and this one is `fun Module:Name/Arity`.